# What is the difference between approximations of mixed derivative and how to implement it

Tags: sparse-matrix, differential-equations, numerical-modelling, matrix-equations

currently I am solving 2D nonlinear second order differential equation containing mixed derivative. I started searching how to descretisize it and found two formulas for 4th order approximation. First one is just kronecker product of first derivatives $D_x\otimes D_y$. Here is fist question: what is resulting order of such approximation if I use like 2nd or 4th order approximations for first derivatives? Second approximation I obtained using Taylor series:
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \dfrac{1}{24h^2}(16(f_{0,-1}+f_{0,1}+f_{-1,0}+f_{1,0}) - (f_{0,-2}+f_{0,2}+f_{-2,0}+f_{2,0})-16(f_{1,-1}+f_{-1,1})+(f_{2,-2}+f_{-2,2})-30f_{0,0})
$$
It is exactly 4th order. Second question: what is the difference between these two approximations (maybe one of these is unstable or smth like that)? As I undertood second should be 13-diagonal matrix, and i wanted to use *toeplitz* to implement it. First one is more complex and it can be implemented using *kron*.
Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You ask what the order is, but then you *state* that it is 4th order. For the second part, you ask about the difference between *two* approximations, but you only show one. Can you clarify?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I listed approximations: 1) $D_x \otimes D_y$ 2) written on a photon I've provided. First approximation comes from simple logic: when we need to analytically take mixed derivative we take them consistently, one by one, so I decided to try this logic using numerical approximations of first derivative (I used 4th order approximation for the first derivative so I assumed resulting order for mixed is also 4th, but I am not sure, so I asked). Second approximation (whis is on a screenshot) I have obtained directly from Taylor expansion.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth So questions were 1) What is the difference between these two approximations (they are different)? Maybe one of them is unstable or has some drawbacks, I dont know. If one is unstable, where can I find prove of it? 2) It is about the first approximation (the one with kronecker product), am I right that usage of 4th order approximation of the first derivatives gives resulting 4th order approximation for the mixed derivative?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Changed picture on LaTeX formula. The first approximation is written in general from, because it depends on order of approximations of the first derivatives